# Google Analytic java include-empty-rows

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i read about google analytic API and trying to use this option of

```
"include-empty-rows"
```

in this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/changelog)  and [this one](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#include-empty-rows)

but i get this error massage

```
<br>Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
<br>{
<br>  "code" : 400,
<br>  "errors" : [ {
<br>    "domain" : "global",
<br>    "message" : "Invalid dimension or metric: ga:include-empty-rows",
<br>    "reason" : "badRequest"
<br>  } ],
<br>  "message" : "Invalid dimension or metric: ga:include-empty-rows"
```

can anyone tell me how to use this option for google analytic ?

tried even in query:

```
query.include-empty-rows
```

but the is no method to use in builder for this parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [include-empty-rows=true](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#include-empty-rows)
>
> Optional.Defaults to true; if set to false, rows without data will be
>   omitted from the response. This can be useful when making a request
>   where it is expected that the number of valid rows is much smaller
>   then the number of expected dimension values.

This is a parameter you tack onto the end of your request.

Example of a request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:78110423&dimensions=ga:date,ga:userType,ga:deviceCategory&metrics=ga:users&start-date=2014-10-01&end-date=2015-12-01&start-index=501&max-results=500&access_token=XXXXXX&quotaUser=d91875d9-cbeb-455a-9a72-9a130809ff1b
```

Example of a request with include empty rows

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:78110423&dimensions=ga:date,ga:userType,ga:deviceCategory&metrics=ga:users&start-date=2014-10-01&end-date=2015-12-01&start-index=501&max-results=500&access_token=XXXXXX&quotaUser=d91875d9-cbeb-455a-9a72-9a130809ff1b&include-empty-rows=true
```

Anwser:

You tack the `include-empty-rows=true` onto your request you appear to have tried to send it as either a dimension or a metric.

Comment: How would i achieve it in this line ?
McfData gaDataPaging = analytics.data().mcf().get("ga:" + config.profileId, startDate.toString(formatter), endDate.toString(formatter), metrics).setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS).setStartIndex(nStartIndex).setDimensions(dimensions).execute();

Comment: You wouldn't the MCF api isn't the same as the Core Reporting api. the mcf api doesn't support include-empty-rows.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/reference

Comment: OK thanks, i would i use it in  

GaData gaData = analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId, startDate, endDate, metrics).setSegment(segment).setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS).setStartIndex(nStartIndex).setDimensions(dimensions).setSamplingLevel("HIGHER_PRECISION").execute();

Comment: yup you can use it there probably something like setIncludeEmptyRows(false)  I don't have the power of java so cant help you test it but it should be something like that.   Remember it defaults to true so if you want it true there is no real reason to set it.

Comment: Is there a way to have `include-empty-rows` for **Realtime Reporting** ?

Comment: no I don't think that API supports it I would submit a feature request